# How I can add blog in my magento site?

Tags: customization, magento

I have to add a blog in my magento site.Is it possible to integrate wordpress into magento by which we are able to post blog in the wordpress and then display in the magento site.

Thanks in advance

Pramod

Comment: Please mention your magento edition

Comment: i am using magnento 1.4.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an extension for this..that you can use

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aheadworks/extension/1516/blog-extension-by-aheadworks

or you can go with ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018827/full-magento-wordpress-integration

Answer (score 2):

You would be much better with the FishPig Magento extension, which will integrate your current WordPress blog into your Magento site in minutes. You can even use your Magento theme for your blog, saving you time and money skinning WordPress to look like Magento.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/wordpress-integration.html